# Too many assets file causes an error?

Tags: android

I can run the project
but i found,if i add to much file,when i build the project,android studio will show the error
this is the error

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkReleaseManifest
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareReleaseDependencies
>   :app:compileReleaseAidl
>   :app:compileReleaseRenderscript
>   :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   :app:mergeReleaseShaders
>   :app:compileReleaseShaders
>   :app:generateReleaseAssets
>   :app:mergeReleaseAssets
>   :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateReleaseResources
>   :app:mergeReleaseResources
>   :app:processReleaseManifest
>   :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\k03\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

i try `clean project` and `rebuild project`,but still show same error

this is the `gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.k03.vv"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
}
```

Comment: make sure  `targeted sdk version in build.gradle file` must match with the `sdk version` which you installed.

Comment: i check the 'tools>android>SDK Manager',i have installed all build tools and api

Comment: and i try to remove the file from assets,then clean project and build project,this is success to build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met this problem before. Usually, the reason is some of your asset doesn't meet the specifications of Android Studio. Try to add the assets in batches,and do `clean project`after each time.Then find the bad one and fix it.

Hope helpful.